Connecting a landline phone with a router hooked up
I have the standard FTTC connection device and a NetComn NF18ACV router.
Seeking better WIFi I bought a TP-Link AX3000 router but it doesn't have a phone line port.
Can I just use the port on the FTTC device?

Have you tried connecting it to see what happens?

Not yet, but I'm looking for  a double adapter as I write

This is the sort of thing where the first thing to do is to try it. Once you've tried it, IF it doesn't work, then we might be able to help, possibly, as you add further information about the service and configuration and devices.

Did I perhaps misunderstand your question? I took your question from the headline, where you're trying to connect a landline phone after you've added a new wireless router to your home network. But Spiff appears to have read that you are trying to connect a wireless router into an RJ11 phone jack on a DSL model. Reading your question a few more times, I cannot tell which of us is correct. Please look at both your headline and your question body, then EDIT your post and clearly indicate what it is you are trying to do. Also, try it first.

@GrantCampbell Do you use the VOIP (phone) capabilities of your current router - specifically, if you still need that functionality it may limit other options.

I now agree with DavidT's suspicion that OP is specifically on Australia's "nbn" FTTC, which works a little differently in that it doesn't support analog telephone service on the DSL line. OP's old router was also a VoIP ATA, but his new router isn't, so now he doesn't have a VoIP ATA to connect his analog phone into. OP, you can probably still use your old router just for its VoIP ATA feature, without using any of its other features. Just plug an Ethernet cable from its WAN Ethernet port to the new router's LAN port. Or ask your local phone and Internet provider for help.

Thanks for your comments. I've decided to have a go at a Grandstream HT812 2 Port VoIP Adapter. Hasn't arrived yet so hoping that will do the trick.
